# is this code making sense at all?

Tags: c++

what does `return 4 return 2 return 6` in this code really returning is not making sense to me may someone explain to me what they return,i saw this code on stack flow someone wanted an explanation on infix and prefix convertion

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#define MAX 20 

char stack[MAX]; 
int top = -1; 
char pop(); 
void push(char item); 

int prcd(char symbol) 
{ 
    switch(symbol) 
    { 
    case '+': 
    case '-': 
        return 2; 
    case '*': 
    case '/': 
        return 4; 
    case '^': 
    case '$': 
        return 6; 
    case '(': 
    case ')': 
    case '#': 
        return 1; 
    } 
} 

int isoperator(char symbol) 
{ 
    switch(symbol) 
    {
    case '+': 
    case '-': 
    case '*': 
    case '/': 
    case '^': 
    case '$': 
    case '(': 
    case ')': 
        return 1; 
    default: 
        return 0; 
    } 
} 

void convertip(char infix[],char prefix[]) 
{ 
    int i,symbol,j=0; 
    char test[MAX]; 

    infix=strrev(infix); 
    stack[++top]='#'; 

    for(i=0;i<strlen(infix);i++) 
    { 
        symbol=infix[i]; 
        if(isoperator(symbol)==0) 
        { 
            prefix[j]=symbol; 
            j++; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            if(symbol==')') 
            { 
                push(symbol); 
            } 
            else if(symbol=='(') 
            {    
                while(stack[top]!=')') 
                { 
                    prefix[j]=pop(); 
                    j++; 
                }    

                pop();//pop out (. 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                if(prcd(symbol)>prcd(stack[top])) 
                { 
                    push(symbol); 
                }
                else 
                { 
                    while(prcd(symbol)<=prcd(stack[top])) 
                    { 
                        prefix[j]=pop(); 
                        j++; 
                    } 
                    push(symbol); 
                }//end of else. 
            }//end of else. 
        }//end of else. 
    }//end of for. 

    while(stack[top]!='#') 
    { 
        prefix[j]=pop(); 
        j++; 
    } 

    prefix[j]='\0';//null terminate string. 
    prefix=strrev(prefix); 

} 

int main() 
{ 
    char infix[20],prefix[20]; 
    //clrscr(); 
    printf("Enter the valid infix string:\n"); 
    gets(infix); 
    convertip(infix,prefix); 
    printf("The corresponding prefix string is:\n"); 
    puts(prefix); 
    getch(); 

    return 0; 
} 

void push(char item)
{ 
    top++; 
    stack[top]=item; 
} 

char pop() 
{ 
    char a; 
    a=stack[top]; 
    top--; 
    return a; 
}
```

Comment: Try to put only the interesting part. People here are not going to read all of that.

Comment: Could you separate the question into sentences? Short answer: it does make sense. [Switch statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)

Comment: This question has been linked to a bug on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153048/code-indenting-just-appears-to-be-broken-here due to some issues with formatting the actual code which several of us seemed to be attempting to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might interpret numerical terms, like. 17 + 3 * 8. To calculate this properly, the code must determine to first take the * and then the +. The order of evaluation is set by the precedence rules: * and / come before + and -.

The `return` statements look like some precedence code.

- (, ), #: `return 1`
- +, -: `return 2`
- *, /: `return 4`
- ^, $: `return 6`

(, ) and # have lowest precedence. After that + and - have next lowest precedence. Then follows * and /. Highest precedence is for ^ and $.

Comment: im trying to get some sense out of it when u write code for example a sum of two number some times i can write return  b+c i know that there is b and c in the code and the return type is the sum but in this code im confused

Comment: @MildredShimz: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: thanks i got the meaning i was confused though

Comment: strange because parentheses have the highest precedence, however ( and ) are not operators, they are just there to parse expressions. You could say that operator precedence is used where ( and ) are not present to show where they should be inserted.

Comment: @CashCow That's why I modified my answer to "*might* interpret numerical terms". It seems to be some sort of precedence as the function name suggests.